# Graph performance in IBM Bluemix tutorial on Twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, message-hub, tone-analyzer

I followed this great [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/01/15/real-time-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-hashtags-with-spark/) by DAVID TAIEB successfully .
The problem is the graph takes so long to change .It takes approximately have minute ,not few seconds, as it supposed to be !!

What could be the problem ?

when I run this cell in the Scala Notebook :

```
demo.startTwitterStreaming(sc)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Registering JaasConfiguration: /tmp/1sFcnUVoabfuBAyF/jaas.conf
Setting hadoop configuration for swift container
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
default location of ssl Trust store is: /usr/local/src/spark160master/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Twitter stream started
Tweets are collected real-time and analyzed
To stop the streaming and start interacting with the data use: StreamingTwitter.stopTwitterStreaming
Receiver Started: KafkaReceiver-0
Batch started with 0 records
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1460572070000 ms
-------------------------------------------

Batch completed with 0 records
Batch started with 0 records
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1460572075000 ms
-------------------------------------------

Batch completed with 0 records
Batch started with 487 records
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1460572080000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(#TDS,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(30.5, 0.0, 16.5, 0.0, 19.5, 3.0, 38.5, 20.0, 5.0, 32.0, 28.0, 9.0, 0.0)))
(#DolceAmoreILoveYou,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(5.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 17.0, 1.0, 17.5, 12.5, 24.5, 34.0, 44.0, 2.0, 0.0)))
(#nasty,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(0.5, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.5, 34.5, 49.0, 1.0, 0.0, 46.0, 16.0, 2.5, 0.0)))
(#Job:,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(8.0, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 28.0, 1.5, 4.5, 2.5, 45.0, 19.5, 37.0, 3.5, 0.0)))
(#bigbrand,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(5.5, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 49.0, 4.0, 2.0, 15.0, 12.5, 3.5, 48.5, 5.5, 0.0)))
(#SwitchUp,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(47.5, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 34.5, 1.0, 47.0, 29.0, 11.5, 22.5, 1.0, 3.5, 0.0)))
(#Hiring,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(8.0, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 28.0, 1.5, 4.5, 2.5, 45.0, 19.5, 37.0, 3.5, 0.0)))
(#entrepreneurship,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(20.5, 25.5, 5.0, 0.0, 28.0, 9.0, 12.0, 3.0, 28.0, 4.0, 12.5, 2.5, 0.0)))
(#startup,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(5.5, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 49.0, 4.0, 2.0, 15.0, 12.5, 3.5, 48.5, 5.5, 0.0)))
(#porn,(1,List(agreeableness_big5, analytical, anger, confident, conscientiousness_big5, disgust, extraversion_big5, fear, joy, neuroticism_big5, openness_big5, sadness, tentative),List(0.5, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.5, 34.5, 49.0, 1.0, 0.0, 46.0, 16.0, 2.5, 0.0)))
...
```

It does not looks like what the tutorial shows :
https://i0.wp.com/developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/wp-content/uploads/sites/47/2016/01/Running-Spark-Streaming.png?zoom=2&w=980

I hope you can help me .What causing my graph not change every few seconds?

When I close the application and the kernal and try to reopen them , this is what I do :

1- restart the kernel 
2- run the all cells again

is this right ?

thank you  @DavidTaieb

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial recently went through an update due to api changes in underlying services (MessageHub, MessageConnect and Watson Tone Analyzer). As part of the changes I added a StreamingListener to provide more granular logging messages. Unfortunately, I forgot to update the screen shot that shows the running cells. In any case, you are running the latest version which is great.
From the snippet you included, it looks like the micro-batches are correctly processed and results are successfully sent to MessageHub/Kafka. The dashboard is configured to poll MessageHub every few seconds, but it seems that it takes a full minute for you to refresh. I re-ran the app on my test environment and I started to notice the same thing. Looking at the logs, I noticed that rest calls to MessageHub started to return 409 error code. Restarting the front-end app did help resolve that issue. I suggest you do the same to unblock you. I will investigate this error further in the coming days and will provide an update once I have an acceptable fix.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Taieb . I **restarted** the front-end app from [here](http://s24.postimg.org/9k7j6tkol/restart.jpg) , but it did not solve the issue .It still take a whole minute until the graph change :(

Comment: I'm working on a fix to avoid concurrent request to MessageHub. Will post here when update is delivered (sometimes next week)

Comment: @fano: I've provided multiple fixes to the project, please redeploy the app and restart the Spark Streaming in the Notebook.  
Fixes:  
1. Fixed the 409 error by serializing all rest calls to MessageHub
2. Fixed an issue related to how I decided whether to update the graph or not.

Note: you may still see delays in the graph update. Remember that the graphs only show data for the top 5 hashtags and not every micro-batches will change them. To provide better feedback, I have added the total number of tweets being processed, this number should update continuously

Answer (score 0):

Message Hub is set to return a 409 error code if a consumer request is made  before the previous one has been completed. Increased the poll interval should solve this issue.

Another issue I have found within the sample provided is that there are boostrap servers set with both ports 9094 and 9093. As of the 3rd March, port 9094 has been switched off. Please ensure you are only using port 9093.

Comment: I already have a mechanism in place to wait for a request to complete before issuing a new one (see [MessageHubBridge.js](https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/Spark-Twitter-Watson-Dashboard/blob/master/server/messageHubBridge.js) line 101. However, I am assuming that 409 conflicts arise only for requests with the same topic, and that 2 requests with different topics can be sent at the same time. Is that not the case?

Comment: The docs [here](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#errors) specify a 40901 error as the following:

_"Error code 40901 – Consumer has already initiated a subscription. Consumers may subscribe to multiple topics, but all subscriptions must be initiated in a single request."_ So I believe that concurrent requests cannot be made from a single instance

Answer (score 0):

I get the following error when I tried the tutorial an hour ago, from the cell containing the following command:
"demo.startTwitterStreaming(sc)"

Registering JaasConfiguration: /tmp/BA8rP92KZiZZSkpq/jaas.conf
Setting hadoop configuration for swift container
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics

Clicking the above links says - {"error_code":40101,"message":"Missing Key"}

Out[3]:

Name: java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: null
StackTrace: org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient$AuthenticationPost.extractResult(SwiftRestClient.java:1293)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient$AuthenticationPost.extractResult(SwiftRestClient.java:1245)......

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)